# Issue with Git merge

Tags: git, merge

I have the following issue on git merge.
Initially we had 2 branches, 1 is master and the other is alpha on which we have the changes. Now we created a new branch called beta from the tip of master and pushed it.We would like to merge the changes from alpha on to beta. This is what we followed:
1)clone the repository
2)checked out to Beta and then did a merge using tortoise git.
3)we were able to see 51 conflicts and we resolved one among them and pushed it to the repo.
4)Now, when we tried to resolve remaining 50 conflicts, we got a message saying that project is up to date.
We are not able to see the changes both on our local and remote.Please can any of you guide me on the right approach?

Answer (score 0):

Resolving conflicts is hard. You cannot commit a branch during merge and resume it later. If you do commit a conflicted branch it's considered as merged anyway (that is why you get "up to date" message). Also you will get merge markers (<<<<<<<<< , ==========, >>>>>>>>>>) inside your files so your code probably won't even compile. The right approach is commiting only after all conflicts are resolved.